# Javascript - lots of standalone functions are bad ??? (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, design-patterns, refactoring

I am refactoring my code now..and I have to refactor my lots of if..else statements, so I am now creating many functions by each conditions.

Code:

```
class Strategy {
    constructor(state) {
        this.state = state;

        if(this.state === 1){
          return first();
        }else if (val === 2){
          return second();
        }else if (val === 3){
          return third();
        }
    }

}

function first(){
  //do something
}

function second(){
  //do something
}

function third(){
  //do something
}

let firstClass = new Strategy(1);
```

Is it OK to declare all each functions by condition???
Or, Is it better to declare each functions in prototype method?/?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't think `constructor()` is meant to return anything. You simply use it to initialize an instance. But unless the functions are shared somewhere else, it would be better to include them inline as anonymous functions

Comment: better way is to prototype your function and use switch case to execute function.

Comment: thank you all guys

Answer (score 1):

you could also use plain JS object as a strategy map, like this:

```
const strategies = {
    1: () => {},  //do something
    2: () => {},   //do something
    3: () => {}   //do something
}
```

and the you can use it like this:

```
strategies[state]();
```

Hope this helps.